# protobuf-net and rpc over tcp

Tags: c#, .net, rpc, protobuf-net, protocol-buffers

I'm looking for a rpc over tcp implementation that uses protobuf-net (or any other .net implementation of protobuf).

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Paul Page not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

protobuf (under *any* implementation) is not an RPC stack; it is a serialization stack. You *can*, however, use WCF to provide the RPC, but hook protobuf-net as the [serialization layer *inside* WCF](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/controlling-wcf-protobuf-net-at.html). That do?

I have a bespoke RPC layer using http, but I haven't implemented one for TCP, and I haven't looked at callbacks. WCF provides these built in, so maybe that is worth looking at?

Comment: I rephrased the question now.

Answer (score 1):

For a different RPC implementation that supports protobuf-net, have a look at [protobuf-remote](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-remote/). It supports both C++ (using the official implementation) and C# (using protobuf-net). Communication is done using TCP.

I have used it myself to connect from a C# client to a C++ server, and send Proto messages.